# CSS - How to Scale Down Images Proportionally When Shrinking Down The Window Dimensions

Tags: html, css, image

I have four images listed horizontally and I want to try to scale it down proportionally and make it responsive as I scale the window down.

I've tried using media queries to no avail. I am pretty new to web development so I do not know how to make pages responsive so any advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
.linkedin-image img,
.github-image img,
.resume-image img,
.email-image img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the image takes the full width of its parent container */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}

.linkedin-image {
    position: fixed; /* Fix the image positions */
    top: 37vh; /* Place the images vertically from the top */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Center the images vertically */
    width: 148px; /* Set the width of the images */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    z-index: 1; /* Set z-index higher than the background but lower than the navbar */
}

.github-image {
    position: fixed; /* Fix the image positions */
    top: 37vh; /* Place the images vertically from the top */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Center the images vertically */
    width: 154px; /* Set the width of the images */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    z-index: 1; /* Set z-index higher than the background but lower than the navbar */
}

.resume-image {
    position: fixed; /* Fix the image position */
    top: 37vh; /* Place the image at the top */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Move image to the left center of the top half */
    z-index: 1; /* Set z-index higher than the background and other elements */
    width: 140px; /* Set the width of the resume image */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}

.email-image {
    position: fixed; /* Fix the image positions */
    top: 37vh; /* Place the images at the bottom */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Move image to the left center of the bottom half */
    z-index: 1; /* Set z-index higher than the background and other elements */
    width: 140px; /* Set the width of the email icon */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}

/* Horizontal stacking of images with more spacing and even distribution */
.linkedin-image {
    left: 2%; /* Adjust the left position as needed */
    bottom: 1.76%; /* Adjust the bottom position as needed */
}

.github-image {
    left: 21.1%; /* Adjust the left position as needed for increased spacing */
    bottom: 1.76%; /* Adjust the bottom position as needed */
}

.resume-image {
    right: 21.1%; /* Adjust the left position as needed for increased spacing */
    bottom: 1.76%; /* Adjust the bottom position as needed */
}

.email-image {
    right: 2%; /* Adjust the left position as needed for increased spacing */
    bottom: 1.76%; /* Adjust the bottom position as needed */
}
```

Comment: I suspect, but cannot be certain, that there is some misunderstanding of use of some CSS properties. Can you please include the relevant HTML. And using fixed units such as px will not be possible in a responsive layout. Investigate e.g. %.

Comment: Can you please include the relevant HTML for this?